# Split Leaflet layer control into multiple tabs panel

Tags: leaflet, layer-control

I have a Leaflet map with several layers (21) grouped into 7 categories.

Because of the large number of layers, I would like to give up on the standard `L.control.layers` look and turn it into a `Bootstrap panel with tabs`, based on my categories.

So I currently have this:
[image]

And I want to achieve this:

[image]

**Is is possible to split the Leaflet layer control into a multiple tabs panel?**

I have added my code to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/synjrLze/4/). I only used some markers, for simplicity.

-- Edit --

I have tried using [Leaflet.StyledLayerControl](https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl) plugin to group my layers and move them to each tab based on their category.

**Result**: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/synjrLze/6/).

**Problem**: After moving the elements, their styling and the click event are lost.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

I suggest you have a look at the [layer switching controls](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls) section of the leaflet plugins page; there are several plugins that implement complex layer controls, and maybe you can benefit from one of them.

Ultimately, you can create your own HTML input elements (checkboxes/radio buttons/drop-downs/etc), attach event listeners to their `change` event, and call `layer.addTo(map)`/`layer.remove()` as needed, keeping references to your instances of `L.Layer`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I was also thinking about using the `styledLayerControl` plugin. I have tried to use it  and, while it's been easy to move the layers from the `layer-control` to each tab based on categories, something odd happens: after moving the elements, they lose their styling and the click event. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/synjrLze/6/)